# PHP set the value of a radio group dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-group

To allow a user to edit information in a record, this is done:

```
$case=$_GET['case'];

$query="SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `case`= '$case'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
```

I need to set the value of a radio group based on what its value is in the "cases" table.

```
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="AM" />
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="PM"  />
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You want to **select** either "AM" or "PM" based on some value in the `cases` table...?

Comment: Do you mean setting the `checked="checked"` attribute on the appropriate radio button or creating a series of radio buttons for each row returned by the query, each having a different `value` attribute?

Comment: Setting the checked attribute to the appropriate radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input <?php if ($somevalue == 'AM') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="AM" />
<input <?php if ($somevalue == 'PM') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="PM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a known value `$val`, you just need to check it against each radio button value and set the `checked` attribute, eg

```
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="AM"
       <?php if ($val == 'AM') : ?>checked="checked"<?php endif ?>
       />
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="PM"
       <?php if ($val == 'PM') : ?>checked="checked"<?php endif ?>
       />
```

That example is very manual. It would be easier if the radio elements are created in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a little ambiguous but I'm going on the assumption that you mean you need to determine which value is default checked based on the value in the cases table?

Something like,

```
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="AM" <?php if ($some_cases_value) { print 'CHECKED'; } ?>/>
<input type="radio" name="flight1_departing" value="PM" <?php if ($some_cases_value) { print 'CHECKED'; } ?> />
```

Though there is likely a very more elegant way of doing it?